# Check if the user is looged in using google account

Tags: android

I am making an android app which provides login using google. I have successfully logged in. Now I want to take the user directly to the dashboard next time he opens the app. So how to check whether he is already logged in using google account or not.

Comment: use shredpreference..Store login id in pref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `silentSignIn` as shown below from `GoogleSignInApi`. Its awesome. And also use sharedPreference to maintain the state as loggedIn or loggedOut.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    //If the user is signIn and cached or else try again logging
    Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in|| " + opr.isDone());

    if (opr.isDone() && BankerPrefs.isLogin(this)) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```